# Connect to 8Base API with TLS on Arduino Uno Wifi Rev2

Tags: http, networking, arduino-uno-wifi

I'm trying hit some endpoints on the 8Base API with the Arduino Uno Wifi Rev2. I was able to get this API call to work with Postman, but I've had no luck once I convert it to my Arduino code. In Postman, clicking the "Code" button reveals that this is what the successful Postman request looks like:

```
POST /MY_PATH HTTP/1.1
Host: api.8base.com
Authorization: Bearer MY_TOKEN
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 64

{
    "query": "{ listOfMachinesList { items{ machineID } } }"
}
```

Here's what the relevant parts of my Arduino code look like after translating this API call into my Arduino:

```
#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <Arduino.h>

WiFiSSLClient client;
char server[] = "api.8base.com";

const String requestBody = "{\"query\": \"{ listOfMachinesList { items{ machineID } } }\"}";
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;


void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("Starting");
  status = WiFi.begin(WifiSSID, WifiPassword);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) { 
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Waiting for connection");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to wifi");
  attemptConnect();

}

void attemptConnect() { 

  Serial.println("\nStarting connection to server...");

  if (client.connectSSL(server, 443)) {
    Serial.println("connected to server");
    // Make a HTTP request:
    client.print("POST /MY_PATH HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/2.2.0");
    client.print("Authorization: Bearer "); 
    client.println(String(APIKey));
    client.println("Content-type: application/json");        
    client.print("Host: "); 
    client.println(server);
    client.println("Connection: keep-alive"); 
    client.println();
    Serial.println("finished POST request");
  } else {
    Serial.println("didn't connect");
  }

}
```

The connection appears to fail on"client.connectSSL(server, 443)" before it can get inside the "if". My Serial Monitor shows the "didn't connect" message. Further, I added some additional Serial.println statements inside the connectSSL function. It looks like the connection fails in a function called void ServerDrv::startClient'", specifically here:

```
 if (!SpiDrv::waitResponseCmd(START_CLIENT_TCP_CMD, PARAM_NUMS_1, &_data, &_dataLen))
 {
        WARN("error waitResponse");
 }
```

I added the certificates from both api.8base.com and 8base.com following the instructions here: https://support.arduino.cc/hc/en-us/articles/360016119219-How-to-add-certificates-to-Wifi-Nina-Wifi-101-Modules-

Using this code and the certificate instructions above, I was able to connect to google.com on port 443, but no luck with 8base. I know that 8base uses GraphQL for their connections, but I was able to hit another GraphQL endpoint on a different, non-SSL server. I also checked to see if 8base was using a non-standard port, but, according to Postman, it is using 443. I'm a little confused why I can't get past the connectSSL function. On the surface, it seems like it should behave the same way as it does when I connect to Google, but there must be something else going on that I'm missing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I am passing this along to our support team to take a look. Please send me an email so we can be in touch at albert@8base.com. Thanks and best of luck! Albert

Comment: Thanks, Albert! I'll reach out over email

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, our 8base team doesn't have much knowledge/content around C++. That said, I'd check out the following.

1. Here's a high-level HTTP client for Arduino that's modeled after the browser fetch API: https://github.com/instanceofMA/arduino-fetch
2. You wrote the API string as "api.8base.com". Try it with the full API endpoint; "https://api.8base.com/WORKSPACE_ID" (where is your workspace ID?)

LMK if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Unfortunately, it looks like that library is only for ESP8266 and ESP32 modules. I was using the Arduino Uno Wifi Rev 2. I tried adding the workspaceID and got the same result. I was adding the workspaceID    in the client.print("POST /MY_PATH HTTP/1.1"); line. That seemed to work with another GraphQL request. Maybe I'm missing something important about how the 8base API is setup, though

Comment: Hmmm...yeah the 8base API is a very standard implementation of a GraphQL API. We didn't implement anything funky as far as I know! Would you be able to try deploying a webhook function and seeing if you're able to get a response from a HTTPS GET request?

Comment: I gave that a shot, as well. I also tried with a new free-tier account to make sure that it wasn't simply an issue with that account. I still can't get past the client.connectSSL(server, 443) line, unfortunately. Do you know if any other customers have connected to their endpoints with an Arduino?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't. We do not have a way of determining what devices incoming traffic to workspaces originates from. Also, even if we did, we couldn't share it lol! You're the first to reach out regarding this. So please keep us informed on the process and I'll keep digging as well.